# Typescript type checking with Gatsby

Tags: javascript, typescript, gatsby

I am building a website using gatsby and typescript. I am using the `gatsby-plugin-typescript` for the transpilation and am trying to get build-step type-checking via an npm script.

```
"scripts": {
 "develop": "gatsby develop",
 "start:ts": "npm run type-check && run-p develop type-check:watch",
 "type-check": "tsc --noEmit",
 "type-check:watch": "npm run type-check -- --watch"
}
```

If I run `yarn start:ts` the build stops on an initial ts error and does not compile all the gatsby stuff. So far so good. 
But the problem is: if I produce a ts error LATER while tsc is watching, typescript recognises the error and prints it to the console BUT does not exit the process. Therefor `run-p` (which is essentially for `npm-run-all -p`) does not "see" the error and continues running `gatsby develop`.

What I would want is for the build to be blocked or stopped if I have TS errors so I can see them immediately while developing.

Anybody got an idea how I can make the type-check blocking at any time?

Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: Have you found an answer? I've also run into a similar problem.